# Custom Exceptions in Clojure?

Tags: exception, clojure

I've been trying to create a user-defined exception in Clojure, and have been having all sorts of problems.  I tried the method outlined here:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Concepts#User-Defined_Exceptions

```
(gen-and-load-class 'user.MyException :extends Exception)
```

But that doesn't seem to work in Clojure 1.2 (or I'm doing something wrong...).  My environment is Clojure 1.2, Emacs, and lein swank.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make a file `src/user/MyException.clj` (where `src` is on `CLASSPATH`) containing:

```
(ns user.MyException
  (:gen-class :extends java.lang.Exception))
```

Check the value of `*compile-path*` at the REPL.  Make sure this directory exists and is on `CLASSPATH`.  Create the directory if it doesn't exist; Clojure won't do so for you.

```
user> *compile-path*
"/home/user/foo/target/classes/"
user> (System/getProperty "java.class.path")
".......:/home/user/foo/target/classes/:......."
```

Compile your class:

```
user> (compile 'user.MyException)
user.MyException
```

If it worked, in `*compile-path*` you should now have files something like this:

```
/home/user/foo/target/
/home/user/foo/target/classes
/home/user/foo/target/classes/user
/home/user/foo/target/classes/user/MyException.class
/home/user/foo/target/classes/user/MyException__init.class
/home/user/foo/target/classes/user/MyException$loading__4410__auto__.class
```

Restart your Clojure REPL / JVM to load these classes.  Again, make sure these new class files are on `CLASSPATH`.  Now you should be able to use your class:

```
user> (user.MyException.)
#<MyException user.MyException>
```

Answer (score 77):

Rather than generating custom classes, there are two much simpler ways to use custom exceptions:

1. Use [slingshot](https://github.com/scgilardi/slingshot) - this provides custom `throw+` and `catch+` macros that let you throw and catch any object, as well as exceptions.
2. In clojure 1.4 and above, you can use [clojure.core/ex-info](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ex-info) and [clojure.core/ex-data](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ex-data) to generate and catch a `clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo` class, which wraps a message and a map of data.

Using this is straightforward:

```
(throw (ex-info "My hovercraft is full of eels"
                {:type :python-exception, :cause :eels}))

(try (...)
  (catch clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo e
    (if (= :eels (-> e ex-data :cause))
      (println "beware the shrieking eels!")
      (println "???"))))
```

Or in a midje test:

```
(fact "should throw some eels"
    (...) 
    => (throws clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo
          #(= :eels (-> % ex-data :cause))))
```

Comment: Many thanks, I've looked for a long time for a simple solution to trasparent exception management in Clojure!

Comment: for custom exceptions in ring-service, i'd recommend using the approach suggested here: https://8thlight.com/blog/mike-knepper/2015/05/19/handling-exceptions-with-middleware-in-clojure.html

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, unless you are creating a custom exception for interop reasons you may want to consider using `clojure.contrib.condition` instead.  It comes with a precompiled custom exception that you piggy-back custom data onto using it's API.  I've been able to avoid creating many custom exceptions by using it instead.  The docs are here:
http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/condition-api.html

Comment: `clojure-contrib` is now deprecated.