# How to test for texts not fitting an Instaparse-grammar (Clojure)?

Tags: parsing, exception, clojure, context-free-grammar, instaparse

I wrote a project for parsing strings using context-free grammar in Instaparse (Clojure). Now I'd like to test several input-Strings for their parsing results. Some input strings might not fit into the grammar. So far I only tested for "parsed strings not fitting the expectation". But I think it would be more accurate to test for exceptions using `(is (thrown? ...))`. Are there exceptions thrown? It seems to me that some output (Containing `Parse error...`) is generated, but no exception is thrown.

My project.clj is:

```
(defproject com.stackoverflow.clojure/tests "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Tests of Clojure test-framework."
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [instaparse "1.3.4"]])
```

My core source is:

```
(ns com.stackoverflow.clojure.testInstaparseWrongGrammar
  (:require [instaparse.core :as insta]))

(def parser (insta/parser "
    <sentence> = words <DOT>
    DOT        = '.'
    <words>    = word (<SPACE> word)*
    SPACE      = ' '
    word     = #'(?U)\\w+'
"))

(defn formatter [expr] 
  (->> (parser expr)
       (insta/transform {:word identity})
       (apply str)))
```

My test source is:

```
(ns com.stackoverflow.clojure.testInstaparseWrongGrammar-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [com.stackoverflow.clojure.testInstaparseWrongGrammar :refer :all]))

(deftest parser-tests
  (is (= [[:word "Hello"] [:word "World"]] (parser "Hello World.")))
  (is (not (= [[:word "Hello"] [:word "World"]] (parser "Hello World?"))))
  ;(parser "Hello World?")     gives:
  ;
  ;Parse error at line 1, column 12:
  ;Hello World?
  ;           ^
  ;Expected one of:
  ;"." (followed by end-of-string)
  ;" "
)

(deftest formatter-tests
  (is (= "HelloWorld" (formatter "Hello World.")))
  (is (not (= "HelloWorld" (formatter "Hello World?"))))
  ;(formatter "Hello World?")     gives:
  ;"[:index 11][:reason [{:tag :string, :expecting \".\", :full true} {:tag :string, :expecting \" \"}]][:text \"Hello World?\"][:column 12][:line 1]"
)

; run the tests
(run-tests)
```

How should I test for the errors (Here: when the sentence does not end with a `.` but with a `!`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instaparse does not throw an exception on a parse error; instead, it returns a "failure object" (ref: [parse errors](https://github.com/engelberg/instaparse#parse-errors)).  You can test for a failure object with `(insta/failure? result)`.

If you want your parser/formatter to throw an exception on unexpected input, add that to your core:

```
(ns com.stackoverflow.clojure.testInstaparseWrongGrammar
  (:require [instaparse.core :as insta])
  (:require [instaparse.failure :as fail]))

(def raw-parser (insta/parser "
    <sentence> = words <DOT>
    DOT        = '.'
    <words>    = word (<SPACE> word)*
    SPACE      = ' '
    word     = #'(?U)\\w+'
"))

; pretty-print a failure as a string
(defn- failure->string [result]
  (with-out-str (fail/pprint-failure result)))

; create an Exception with the pretty-printed failure message
(defn- failure->exn [result]
  (Exception. (failure->string result)))  

(defn parser [expr]
  (let [result (raw-parser expr)]
    (if (insta/failure? result)
      (throw (failure->exn result))
      result)))

(defn formatter [expr]
  (->> (parser expr)
       (insta/transform {:word identity})
       (apply str)))
```

...and now you can use `(is (thrown? ...))` in the test:

```
(deftest parser-tests
  (is (= [[:word "Hello"] [:word "World"]] (parser "Hello World.")))
  (is (thrown? Exception (= [[:word "Hello"] [:word "World"]] (parser "Hello World?"))))
```

This approach uses instaparse to pretty-print the failure and wraps that in an Exception.  Another approach is to use `ex-info` as outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16159584).

Comment: How do I get the information from the failure-object? For the beginning I'd like to do two things (if possible). **First**: Add the line-number to my exception method. **Second**: Add the nicely-formatted error-message to my exception. **Moreover**, for creating a new Exception class, it seems to be the easiest way to implement it in Java - is that correct?

Comment: ... and what exactly do you mean by `failure object`. I thought there a no Objects (with methods and variables) in Clojure. So how can I (in general) access methods and variables of those Objects?

Comment: @Edward the code above now includes a text description of the parse error (line, column, etc.) in the Exception.  The "failure object" is a map (technically a `record` created by `defrecord`) that has some well-known keys; for example, line number can be accessed with `(:line result)`.